# JQuery QueryBuilder not working

Tags: jquery, html, query-builder

I am using [JQuery QueryBuilder](http://mistic100.github.io/jQuery-QueryBuilder/) in my HTML page. I have followed the [installation guide](http://mistic100.github.io/jQuery-QueryBuilder/#installation). My HTML head includes the following

```
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/moment/moment.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/jquery-extendext/jQuery.extendext.js"></script>
    <link href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="bower_components/jQuery-QueryBuilder/dist/css/query-builder.default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="bower_components/jQuery-QueryBuilder/dist/js/query-builder.standalone.js"></script>
```

My body has

```
<div id="builder"></div>
```

But when I use

```
<script>
  $('#builder').queryBuilder({
    filters: [ ... ]
  });
</script>
```

My Chrome console says

```
query-builder.standalone.js:437 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'queryBuilder' of undefined
```

All my bower componenets are installed properly.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you need a html element in ```<body>```: ```<div id="builder"></div>```

Comment: I had included it. I still get the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move the script below the **builder div** element

```
<div id="builder"></div>

<script>
  $('#builder').queryBuilder({
    filters: [{id:1}] // You need to implement this
  });
</script>
```

or use Jquery document.ready

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#builder').queryBuilder({
        filters: [{id:1}] // You need to implement this
    });
  })
```

Comment: But when I use the same inside $(document).ready(function(){...}, I still get the same error. I need to add an onclick listener to the button.

Comment: The error you had seemed to be that when $('#builder') was called, the div was not yet rendered

Comment: if you do console.log($('#builder').length); what do you get?

Comment: console.log($('#builder').length); inside $(document).ready(function(){...} gives me 1. But when I use $('#builder').queryBuilder({}); it throws an error saying Cannot set property 'queryBuilder' of undefined

Comment: Is there a live link to your project?

Comment: Also, try the following in dev tools: 1) in elements tab click the body 2) in console tab type $($0).queryBuilder({});

Comment: $0 chooses the element selected in elements tab

Comment: $($0).queryBuilder is undefined